# Delete modal contents and display new contents

Tags: javascript, html

Hi friends I have a modal that has a button inside

I want the current contents of my modal to be deleted when that button is clicked

And then the new content, which is an input, appears after a few seconds of loading

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Connect</p>
            <div class="wall">
                <div class="sc-bYSBpT kxgAIA">
                    <div class="sc-kTUwUJ hsKMjF">
                        <button  class="sc-jbKcbu sc-dNLxif sc-uJMKN licBat">
                                <div class="sc-jqCOkK irnmqJ">
                                    <div color="#E8831D" class="sc-jnlKLf fFNbAV">Install</div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </button>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Uttam I do not receive an error, I just do not know how to implement it and I need help

Comment: @hprogrammer you forgot id of the button.

Comment: @Bataklik I have no problem displaying this modal I have problem displaying new content after clicking the button inside the modal

Comment: where is the new content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if another content is in the modal

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var startContent = document.getElementById("startContent");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

var btnInstall = document.getElementById("btnInstall");
        
var newContent = document.getElementById("newContent");

btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";                       
}
        
btnInstall.onclick = function() {
   startContent.style.display = "none";            
   newContent.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
}                       

window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" >
   myBtn
</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal"  style="display:none">
   <div class="modal-content" id="startContent">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Connect</p>
      <div class="wall">
         <div class="sc-bYSBpT kxgAIA">
            <div class="sc-kTUwUJ hsKMjF">
               <button  class="sc-jbKcbu sc-dNLxif sc-uJMKN licBat">
                  <div class="sc-jqCOkK irnmqJ">
                     <div color="#E8831D" id="btnInstall" class="sc-jnlKLf fFNbAV">Install</div>
                     </div>
               </button>
            </div> 
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="newContent" style="display:none">
      <input type="text">           
   </div>
</div>
```